# Cómo pongo 2 listas separadas por un espacio grande? Html css

Tags: html, css

Estoy aprendiendo y no logro encontrar lo que quiero, que es poner  2 listas en orden pero separadas por 2 tabulaciones por lo menos o alinear la lista de la derecha a la derecha y la lista de la izquierda a la izquierda.
Básicamente busco hacer esto:

```
Lista:   
ºTexto1       ºTexto1   
ºTexto2       ºTexto2
ºTexto3       ºTexto3
ºTexto4       ºTexto4
```

Lo que quiero hacer lo tengo dentro de un `<div>`
Probé poner `&nspb;` varios pero no me gustó como queda.
Probé poner espacios, no funciona.
Probé <align="right"> tampoco funciona
Tampoco sabía si ponerle una etiqueta a cada palabra porque podria hacer un `<p>` para cada una y hacer un align pero son muchas... tengo 47 palabras en la lista.

O que por lo menos la lista tenga por ejemplo una medida de 300px.. si supera los 300 que los elementos empiezen a acomodarse a la derecha haciendo una segunda linea.

Gracias

Comment: Podrías usar [un contenedor flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

Comment: O tambien puedes intentar colocar tu informacion dentro de una tabla. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp  dependerá de lo que sea más conveniente para ti

Comment: @LilibethQ Se usan tablas en html5? además que son responsive? Gracias Triby, lo voy a controlar. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Tefa, tendrías que utilizar el Layout de Flexbox en CSS. Posicionar dos listas en fila con un espacio entre medio, se usa la propiedad flex-direction: row. Es importante tener esas listas dentro de un DIV contenedor, y aplicarle ese estilo al mismo.